# numpy array of numpy arrays of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy object array of size (2x3). Lets call it `M1`. In `M1` there are 6 numpy arrays.
The shapes of arrays in a given row of M1 are the same but differ from the shapes of arrays in any other row of `M1`.

that is,

```
M1 = [ [A1 B1 C1]
       [D1 E1 F1] ]
```

A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1 are 2D numpy arrays. Shapes of A1, B1 and C1 are same. Shapes of D1,E1,F1 are same. `Shape of A1 != D1` and so on.

Similarly I have

```
M2 = [ [A2 B2 C2]
       [D2 E2 F2] ]
```

Now I want a numpy array M3 which is of the same shape as M1.

```
M3 = [ [A3 B3 C3]
       [D3 E3 F3] ]
```

Where `A3[0,0] = [A1[0,0] A2[0,0]]`, `A3[0,1] = [A1[0,1] A2[0,1]]` and so on. (All the elements of M3 will be like this)

Is there a pythonic way to do this without using the for loops?

Also, I'd like to know what changes to make if I want A3[0,0] as:

```
A3[0,0] = [ [A1[0,0] A2[0,0]],
            [B1[0,0] B2[0,0]] ]
```

Comment: something tells me you are working with tensors?

Comment: So, `A3.ndim` will be `3` in the first case and `4` in the second?  I think you'll have trouble vectorizing this sort of thing with `object` arrays -- at least I don't know how to do it :P

Comment: How can M3 be the same shape as M1 when each element contains a _pair_ of elements from M1 _and_ M2? Your question is not totally clear to me...

Comment: @usethedeathstar its something like that but im trying to use numpy arrays

Comment: @HenryGomersall the pair of elements are not tuples but numpy arrays of dimension 2x1

Comment: @askewchan that is just an example...

Comment: I understand .. I'm just asking to make sure I understand the example.  While `M1.shape == M2.shape == M3.shape`, but `M1[i,j].shape == M2[i,j].shape != M3[i,j].shape`.  In fact, it seems `M3[i,j].shape == np.array([M1[i,j], M2[i,j]]).shape == (2,) + M1[i,j].shape`

Comment: @AbhishekThakur but you said A1 etc are 2D arrays, so as you've indexed them, you end up with a scalar. It really isn't clear to me what your question is.

Comment: Give us an iterative solution with sample data (`np.ones` or `np.zeros` will do since we are just worried about combining shapes).  It will then be easier to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get everything you want. You want to use the optimizations of numpy arrays (that is, you want to avoid for-loops), but you want the flexibility to have each row of M1 and M2 to have different shapes. But efficiency requires sacrificing flexibility in this case.

Just break M1 and M2 into different variables, one for each row. Call these M1a and M2a, M1b and M2b, .... Now you can create true 3d numpy arrays.

```
# building blocks ... like your A1, B1, etc
I2 = np.eye(2, dtype=np.int)

# First row of M1
M1a = np.array([I2, 2*I2, 3*I2])

# First row of M2
M2a = -M1a.copy()

# Stick them together such that M3a[0,0] = [M1a[0,0], M2a[0,0]]
M3a = np.transpose([M1a, M2a])
```

Now do the same for rows M1b, M2b, M3b using a building block of a different shape `I3 = np.eye(3)`. So you have a for-loop only over the last dimension.

I know, you want to vectorize the last dimension. But that's not possible if you want to maintain the flexibility of having each row use a different shape. Sorry! No free lunch.